# jquery anonymous function declaration meanings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are the following assumptions accurate?

1) execute immediately

```
(function(){
})();
```

2) execute on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

3) shorthand for on document ready

```
$(function(){
});
```

4) alternative shorthand for on document ready for avoiding cross script conflicts

```
(function($) {
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Last one is often used for defining plugins.

Comment: Edited your numbering to give it nicer code formatting, markdown doesn't like code directly below numbers for whatever reason :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes your definitions are correct, for the first 3 :)

Though, unless you need a closure, a statement will execute immediately, no reason to wrap it like #1 has (there are certainly plenty of valid times you need a closure, just noting if you don't...it's superfluous).

Number 4 however is not correct, `(function($) { })(jQuery);` is not tied to any event, it's just a closure so that `$ === jQuery` inside of it, so you can use the `$` shortcut:

```
(function($) { 
  //You may use $ here instead of jQuery and it'll work...even if $ means
  //something else outside of this closure, another library shortcut for example
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Very informative answer. Is Number 4 mainly used just in case $ has been overwritten in the global scope since jQuery file was loaded?

Comment: @yaya3 - Yes, usually as a result of [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to let another library control `$`.  However if you wanted `document.ready` and no conflicts, there's a short version as well, jQuery passes itself as a parameter to the ready handler so `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { });​` or the shorter `jQuery(function ($) { });​` are getting `$` passed in, more local so `$ === jQuery` inside as well...and the code's triggered on `document.ready`, nice and neat.  Or use any other name :), e.g. `jQuery(function (myVar) { myVar('#myElem').hide(); });​`

Answer (score 9):

Here's the #4 you were looking for:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
});
```

It will run on document.ready, within a namespace, and with jQuery defined as $.

Comment: brilliant way to write this that will give us the power of $ without the downside.